# How can I Merge two Arrays of Objects by Key & Place the Merged data in a Sub Array

Tags: javascript

What tools would I use to merge my new object into a sub array by key on the main object? Let me show you what I mean:

I have this object, which is an example from an array of objects:

```
array1 = [{
    "employeeId": 1,
    "registerID": 1,
    "shopID": 1,
    "completed": true,
    "completeTime": "06/04/2017",
    "referenceNumber": 10001000152,
    "referenceNumberSource": "epos",
    "SaleLines": {
      "SaleLine": [
        {
          "itemID": "JRY",
          "unitQuantity": 1,
          "ItemDescription": "EXPRESS STUFF",
          "Supplier": "JR(Wholesale) Ltd",
          "Cost": 2.52,
          "Price": 5.99,
          "Tax": 1,
          "TotalSales": 6.99
        },
        {
          "itemID": "2HANDGOODS",
          "unitQuantity": 1,
          "ItemDescription": "SECONDHAND GOODS",
          "Supplier": "Some Stuff Limited",
          "Cost": 0,
          "Price": 240,
          "Tax": 0,
          "TotalSales": 240
        }
      ]
    }
  }]
```

I have another array of objects which I have filtered down to the following, example:

```
array2 = [{ItemID:'5101', systemSku:'JRY'}, {ItemID:'5102', systemSku:'2HANDGOODS'}]
```

What I am trying to achieve, is to use the systemSku from array2 to match the itemID in array1 and place the ItemID as the value of itemID and add systemSku to the SaleLine object.
Array1 & Array2 both contain around 5200 objects.

So that a SaleLine in SaleLines on array1 would look like:

```
{
          "ItemID": "5101"
          "systemSku": "JRY",
          "unitQuantity": 1,
          "ItemDescription": "EXPRESS STUFF",
          "Supplier": "JR(Wholesale) Ltd",
          "Cost": 2.52,
          "Price": 5.99,
          "Tax": 1,
          "TotalSales": 6.99
        }
```

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
for (item in newItemsObject) {
  for (sale in sales) {
    if (item.itemID === sale.systemSku) {
      return newObjects = {
        itemID: item.itemID,
        systemSku: item.systemSku,
        completeTime: sales.completeTime
      }
    }
    console.log(newObjects)
  }}
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below :

```
let array1 = [{
                    "employeeId": 1,
                    "registerID": 1,
                    "shopID": 1,
                    "completed": true,
                    "completeTime": "06/04/2017",
                    "referenceNumber": 10001000152,
                    "referenceNumberSource": "epos",
                    "SaleLines": {
                        "SaleLine": [
                            {
                                "itemID": "JRY",
                                "unitQuantity": 1,
                                "ItemDescription": "EXPRESS STUFF",
                                "Supplier": "JR(Wholesale) Ltd",
                                "Cost": 2.52,
                                "Price": 5.99,
                                "Tax": 1,
                                "TotalSales": 6.99
                            },
                            {
                                "itemID": "2HANDGOODS",
                                "unitQuantity": 1,
                                "ItemDescription": "SECONDHAND GOODS",
                                "Supplier": "Some Stuff Limited",
                                "Cost": 0,
                                "Price": 240,
                                "Tax": 0,
                                "TotalSales": 240
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }];
                let array2 = [{ItemID:'5101', systemSku:'JRY'}, {ItemID:'5102', systemSku:'2HANDGOODS'}];

                array1 = array1.map(function (item1) {
                    item1['SaleLines']['SaleLine'] = item1['SaleLines']['SaleLine'].map(function (innerItem) {
                        array2.map(function (item2) {
                            if(item2.systemSku == innerItem.itemID){
                                innerItem['itemID'] = item2['ItemID'];
                                innerItem['systemSku'] = item2['systemSku'];
                            }
                        });
                        return innerItem
                    });
                    return item1
                });
                console.log(array1);
```